# how to access xml tag by attribute of the parent

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, attributes

This is part of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
 <pizzas>

<pizza number="0">
  <title>Tomato &amp; Cheese</title>
  <small>550</small>
  <medium></medium>
  <large>975</large>
</pizza>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<div id="basket">
    <h3 style="text-align:center; position:static;">Your Order:</h3>
    <?php
        $numberSelected = '';
        $_SESSION['link'] = $numberSelected;

        class dom{}

        $dom = new dom;
        $dom = simplexml_load_file("../../menu.xml");

        foreach ($dom->xpath("/menu/*/*") as $item)
        {
            print $item->title;
        }

        print_r($_SESSION);
    ?>
</div>
```

How can I print the title of the pizza/item using the number stored in the $numberSelected variable?

I somehow need to access the value inside the `<title></title>` tag, which is inside its parent e.g. `<pizza number="x">`, where x comes from the variable $numberSelected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the node where its attribute is using `=` thru xpath also:

```
[@number='$numberSelected']
```

So just query it and continue on getting the results if it did yielded. Use `foreach` if you're expecting more:

```
$result = $dom->xpath("//pizza[@number='$numberSelected']");
if(!empty($result)) {
    $pizza = $result[0];
    echo $pizza->title; // and others
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hHZIV7)